# Airflow - Broken DAG: [/var/app/current/dags/product/product_snapshot.py] 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to build a DAG in Airflow. As it is a new project, I've made a new folder, with all product-related DAGs. I get the Broken DAG 'module' object is not callable. Not the DAG id, nor any function is named as the file, so I don't understand the 'module' error. 
Am I supposed to do anything with the new folder I've created

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import datetime
import io
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connections
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def db1_conn():
    # Core Credentials
    db1_hook = BaseHook.get_connection('db1')
    db1_conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db1_hook.schema, user=db1_hook.login,
                                 password=db1_hook.password, host=db1_hook.host,
                                 port=db1_hook.port)
    return db1_conn


def db2_write():
    # Core Write
    db2_hook = BaseHook.get_connection('db2-write')
    db2_conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db2_hook.schema, user=db2_hook.login,
                                 password=db2_hook.password, host=db2_hook.host,
                                 port=db2_hook.port)
    return db2_conn


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Python Callable
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def run_this():
    query = f"""
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (userid) 0                                    AS id,
                                        '{month}'::timestamp                 AS month,
                                        userid,
                                        balance,
                                        transactiondate                      AS last_transaction_date,
                                        transactionexternaluniqueid          AS last_transaction_unique_id
            FROM public.product_view
            WHERE transactiondate < '{month}'
            ORDER BY userid, transactiondate DESC
            """
    data = pd.read_sql(query, db1_conn())
    # Index.
    index_query = """
                  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0)::INT AS id
                  FROM schema.product_snapshot
                  """
    index_start = pd.read_sql(index_query, db1_conn)
    data['id'] = data.index + index_start + 1
    # Write on table.
    buf = io.StringIO()
    stoplightdata_buffer.write(data.to_csv(index=None, header=None))
    buf.seek(0)
    conn = core_write()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.copy_from(buf, table='schema.product_snapshot', sep=',', null='')
    conn.commit()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DAG
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DAG_NAME = 'product_snapshot_dag'

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 22),
    'email': [ 'email@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'sla': timedelta(minutes=30),
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(minutes=50)
}

dag = DAG(DAG_NAME,
          schedule_interval='1 * 1 * *',
          default_args=args)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Postgres Operator
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

product_table_creation = PostgresOperator(task_id='product_table_creation',
                                          postgres_conn_id='connection',
                                          sql='sql/product_table_creation.sql',
                                          dag=dag)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Python Operator
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


product_snapshot_data = PythonOperator(task_id='product_snapshot_data',
                                       provide_context=True,
                                       python_callable=run_this,
                                       dag=dag)


product_table_creation >> product_snapshot_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

The DAG new folder is among other DAG's folders.

Comment: Can you share where the code for `run_this` or how it's imported? That should be a python callable that the `PythonOperator` can call.

Comment: I edited the question with the whole code. @DanielHuang